# Parallax image isn't responsive

Tags: html, css, parallax

I'm trying to create a parallax background but it's not responsive

I know this question have been asked before- I tried all those solution but it's still not working.. Please help!

Also when the code is run on browser, it doesn't show header section

I have to scroll up to see the header section

Here's my code:

Html-

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="herounit">
            <img src="https://vignette.wikia.nocookie.net/phobia/images/f/fc/Dark.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20161109164921" alt="Main Image" class="heroimg"/>
                <header><a href="#"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRz1tUrD3X2T2P2uEh12yZmZWYPpr7yQhy5GNehg3s-ChndJ_iT"/></a></header>                  
                    <div class="description">
                      <p>Pasture he invited mr company shyness. But when shot real her. </br>Chamber her observe visited removal six sending himself boy. </br>At exquisite existence if an oh dependent excellent. Are gay head need down draw. </br>Misery wonder enable mutual get set oppose the uneasy. </br>End why melancholy estimating her had indulgence middletons.</p>
                    </div>                      
            <div class="herotext">
                <div class="contactForm">  
                  <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
                    <fieldset>
                      <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                      <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                      <textarea placeholder="Type your Message Here...." tabindex="5" required></textarea>
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
                    </fieldset>
                  </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css-

```
        *{padding:0;margin:0;border:0}html{overflow:hidden}img{width:100vw}.container{-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch;-webkit-perspective:1px;perspective:1px;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:auto;height:100vh}.herounit{-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;transform-style:preserve-3d}.heroimg{-webkit-transform:translateZ(-1px) scale(2);transform:translateZ(-1px) scale(2);position:relative;top:calc(((100vh - 51.54vw)/ 4) * -2)}



            * {
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
                border: 0;
            }
            *, *:before, *:after {
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            header {
              position: fixed;
              top: 10px;
              left: 0;
              width: 100%;
              text-align: center;
            }
            header img {
              height: 100px;
              width: 150px;
            }
            .description {
              position: absolute;
              float: left;
              top: 12%;
              left: 10px;
              width: 100%;
              font-size: 1.5em;
              line-height: 1.8em;
              height: auto;
              padding: 1em;
              margin: 1em;
              color: #fff;
              text-transform: uppercase;

            }
            .herounit  img{
              height: 100%;
            }
            .herotext {
              position: relative;
              z-index: 2;
              -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
              background-image: url("https://www.jindalpanther.com/upload/pages/contact_us.jpg");
              background-position: center;
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size: cover;
              -webkit-background-size: cover;
              -moz-background-size: cover;
              background-size: cover;
              background-color: #111;
              height: 100%;
              text-align: center;
              padding: 2rem 0 2rem;
              transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
              -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
              -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
              -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in;                  
            }
            .herotext h1 {
              font-size: 30px;
              border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
              width: 350px;
              margin: 50px auto;
              color: #fff;
            }
            .contactForm {
              max-width:700px;
              width:100%;
              margin:0 auto;
              position:relative;
            }
            #contact input[type="text"], #contact input[type="email"], #contact input[type="tel"], #contact input[type="url"], #contact textarea, #contact button[type="submit"] {
        font:400 50px/16px "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; }

            #contact {
              padding:25px;
              margin:50px 0;
            }
            #contact h3 {
              color: #F96;
              display: block;
              font-size: 50px;
              font-weight: 400;
            }
            #contact h4 {
              margin:5px 0 15px;
              display:block;
              font-size:13px;
            }
            fieldset {
              border: medium none !important;
              margin: 0 0 10px;
              min-width: 100%;
              padding: 0;
              width: 100%;
            }
            #contact input[type="text"], #contact input[type="email"], #contact input[type="tel"], #contact input[type="url"], #contact textarea {
              width:100%;
              max-width:700px;
              border-style: solid;
              border-color: #fff;
              border-width: 1px;
              border-radius: 5px;
              margin-bottom: 15px;
              background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
              margin:0 0 5px;
              padding:10px;
              height: 50px;
              font-size: 1em;
              line-height: 1.2em;
              color: #111;
              position: relative;
            }
            #contact input[type="text"]:hover, #contact input[type="email"]:hover, #contact input[type="tel"]:hover, #contact input[type="url"]:hover, #contact textarea:hover {
                -webkit-transition:border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
                -moz-transition:border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
                transition:border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
                border:1px solid #AAA;
            }
            #contact textarea {
              height:300px;
              max-width:100%;
              resize:none;
            }
            #contact button[type="submit"] {
              cursor:pointer;
              margin:0 0 5px;
              padding: 20px;
              margin-top: 20px;
              height: 60px;
              width: 100%;
              max-width: 300px;
              color: #fff;
              font-size: 1.5em;
              border-style: solid;
              border-color: #fff;
              border-width: 1px;
              border-radius: 5px;
              text-transform: uppercase;
              background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
            }
            #contact button[type="submit"]:hover {
              background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
              -webkit-transition:background 0.3s ease-in-out;
              -moz-transition:background 0.3s ease-in-out;
              transition:background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
            }
            #contact button[type="submit"]:active {
              box-shadow:inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
            }
            #contact input:focus, #contact textarea:focus {
              outline:0;
              border:1px solid #999;
            }
            ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
             color:#333;
            }
            :-moz-placeholder {
             color:#333;
            }
            ::-moz-placeholder {
             color:#333;
            }
            :-ms-input-placeholder {
             color:#333;
            }
```

Running jsfiddle example here- [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oqbf3mek/2/)

Answer (score 0):

> Also when the code is run on browser, 
>   it doesn't show header section
>   I have to scroll up to see the header section.

That is because of the autofocus attribute you have set on the input element. When the page loads the browser will jump to it straight away.

Comment: Change `<input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>` to `<input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" required>`

Comment: Can you also help me with the responsive problem?